# Trying to retrieve random post, getting a page

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm trying to retrieve a random post to link to on my site. I have the following code, but the only thing that it seems to retrieve and display is a link to the homepage. Any help would be appreciated!

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 1,
'orderby'          => 'rand',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<a href="';
    echo the_permalink();
    echo '" title="';
    echo the_title();
    echo '">';
    echo the_title();
    echo '</a>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the post type to be a post - try this for your $args instead:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'post', // Specifying you want posts only
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'orderby'          => 'rand',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
);
```

And most importantly, you need to apply the $args to your query, so do this for the loop:

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

See [this in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage).